# Search wild card phrases in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, filter, kibana, elk

I have a working wild card search but it dont accept whitespace. I already tried `match_phrase` but it only search for exact words. This is the search result that I want

**Projects:** "Project One Sample", Project Two Sample" 
**input:** "ect One"
**result:**"Project One Sample"

Here's my working code

```
GET <index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*roj*",
            "fields":["field_1", "field_2"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I just realize that one my fields for query string is timestamp which causing error. Now my problem is `query_string` only search per prefix, it doesnt include the next prefix in searching.
ie 
**Projects:** "Project One Sample", Project Two Sample" 
**input:** "ect One"
**result:**"Project One Sample", Project Two Sample"

Comment: I also tried ```match_phrase_prefix``` but it only search for a word and succeeding prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

The default operator of query_string is `OR` thats why it only display the search result of first prefix. To get the result of prefixes use `AND` operator

source : [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can search like this:

```
*ect One
```

For example:

```
GET <index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*ect One",
            "fields":["field_1", "field_2"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can check [this](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) for more information.

Comment: with what? Can you explain more?

Comment: Your query should be like this to get what you want in your example.

Comment: Too vague. You just repeated my existing code. You see I already used a wildcard in my query

Comment: Yes correct, but It only search per prefix, not the whole prefix  of string.